# Rails: Storing binary files in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails, is there a reason why I should store attachments (could be a file of any time), in the filesystem instead of in the database? The database seems simpler to me, no need to worry about filesystem paths, structure, etc., you just look in your blob field. But most people seem to use the filesystem that it leaves me guessing that there must be some benefits to doing so that I'm not getting, or some disadvantages to using the database for such storage. (In this case, I'm using postgres).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a pretty standard design question, and there isn't really a "one true answer".

The rule of thumb I typically follow is "data goes in databases, files go in files".

Some of the considerations to keep in mind:

1. If a file is stored in the database, how are you going to serve it out via http? Remember, you need to set the content type, filename, etc. If it's a file on the filesystem, the web server takes care of all that stuff for you. Very quickly and efficiently (perhaps even in kernel space), no interpreted code needed.
2. Files are typically big. Big databases are certainly viable, but they are slow and inconvenient to back up etc. Why make your database huge when you don't have to?
3. Much like 2., it's really easy to copy files to multiple machines. Say you're running a cluster, you can just periodically rsync the filesystem from your master machine to your slaves and use standard static http serving. Obviously databases can be clustered as well, it's just not necessarily as intuitive.
4. On the flip side of 3, if you're already clustering your database, then having to deal with clustered files in addition is administrative complexity. This would be a reason to consider storing files in the DB, I'd say.
5. Blob data in databases is typically opaque. You can't filter it, sort by it, or group by it. That lessens the value of storing it in the database.
6. On the flip side, databases understand concurrency. You can use your standard model of transaction isolation to ensure that two clients don't try to edit the same file at the same time. This might be nice. Not to say you couldn't use lockfiles, but now you've got two things to understand instead of one.
7. Accessibility. Files in a filesystem can be opened with regular tools. Vi, Photoshop, Word, whatever you need. This can be convenient. How are you gonna open that word document out of a blob field?
8. Permissions. Filesystems have permissions, and they can be a pain in the rear. Conversely, they might be useful to your application. Permissions will really  bite you if you're taking advantage of 7, because it's almost guaranteed that your web server runs with different permissions than your applications.
9. Cacheing (from sarah mei below). This plays into the http question above on the client side (are you going to remember to set lifetimes correctly?). On the server side files on a filesystem are a very well-understood and optimized access pattern. Large blob fields may or may not be optimized well by your database, and you're almost guaranteed to have an additional network trip from the database to the web server as well.

In short, people tend to use filesystems for files because they support file-like idioms the best. There's no reason you have to do it though, and filesystems are becoming more and more like databases so it wouldn't surprise me at all to see a complete convergence eventually.

Comment: 7. Do you mean working on the server directly? As a file, I'd also download it before opening it in photoshop. Or my versioning system would do that for me.

Comment: Storing things in a local filesystem that isn't replicated often breaks 12factor-style apps, which makes scaling a medium or better app problematic.  Storing attachments in an S3/CloudFront or similar clone backend is the way to go for most (but not all) use-cases.  CarrierWave, Paperclip, etc. can help abstract away those differences.

Answer (score 7):

There's some good advice about using the filesystem for files, but here's something else to think about. If you are storing sensitive or secure files/attachments, using the DB really is the only way to go. I have built apps where the data can't be put out on a file. It has to be put into the DB for security reasons. You can't leave it in a file system for a user on the server/machine to look at or take with them without proper securty.  Using a high-class DB like Oracle, you can lock that data down very tightly and ensure that only appropriate users have access to that data.

But the other points made are very valid.  If you're simply doing things like avatar images or non-sensitive info, the filesystem is generally faster and more convenient for most plugin systems.

The DB is pretty easy to setup for sending files back; it's a little bit more work, but just a few minutes if you know what you're doing.  So yes, the filesystem is the better way to go overall, IMO, but the DB is the only viable choice when security or sensitive data is a major concern.

Comment: This is true. Trying to synchronize security rules across filesystem and database simultaneously is difficult at best.

Comment: While it may be imposible one idea would be something like Linux with .htaccess files on the file system preventing unauthorized web viewers seeing the file, or you could store it out of the public web-server directory and have a refrence link to it. PHP, I know for a fact can pull the file from somewhere not public in the OS if it has the right permisions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what the problem with blobstores is. You can always reconstruct a file system store from it, e.g. by caching the stuff to the local web server while the system is being used.
But the authoritative store should always be the database. Which means you can deploy your application by tossing in the database and exporting the code from source control. Done.
And adding a web server is no issue at all.

Comment: Based on production experience I believe this answer is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Erik's answer is great. I will also add that if you want to do any caching, it's much easier and more straightforward to cache static files than to cache database contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a plugin such as [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree), you don't have to worry about anything either. There's this thing called the filesystem, which is where files should go. Just because it is a bit harder doesn't mean you should put your files in the wrong place. And with paperclip (or other similar plugins) it isn't hard. So, gogo filesystem!

Comment: what about ensuring only the appropriate users can see/access the files - does Paperclip take care of this?

Comment: That's an extreme edge case. Not ever facebook protects their images (other than giving the images very wicked URLs).

Comment: One way to do this would be in production placing files behind an Apache server a .htaccess file could close this off.  The problem?  Getting the files.  I am not sure if this is possible in rails but in PHP, you can grab the file from a .htaccess protected directory after checking if the user has permisions to see it.  The PHP script, of course, is in a different public directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find an up-to-date answer to this question I have implemented an 
database service for Active Storage available since Rails 5.2 that works just like any other Active Storage service, but stores file content in a special database column instead of a cloud service.

The implementation is based on a standard Rails Active Storage service, adding a migration with a new model: an extra table that stores blob contents in a binary field. The service creates and destroys records in this table as requested by Active Storage.

Therefore, this service, once installed, can be consumed via a standard Rails Active Storage API.

https://github.com/TitovDigital/activestorage-database-service

Please be aware of all pros and cons of using a database for storing files.

With the right database it will provide full ACID support and can wrap file storage and deletion into transactions. It is also much easier in DevOps as there is one less service to configure.

Large files or large traffic are the risky cases. Either will put an unnecessary strain on the app and database servers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20685738)

Comment: Thank you @GerhardBarnard, followed your suggestion and added implementation details.

Comment: One more thing to add. All previous answers in this thread have been written before Active Storage has been introduced and as a result are obsolete now, suggesting a custom solution where a standard Rails API now exists.

The reason I commented on this old thread is that it is on top Google search for relevant queries and provided zero useful information as of 2018.