# iphone sqlite to Ruby on rails question

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, core-data, sqlite

Im making an app for iphone that sends for caching an sqlite to a server using Ruby on rails,

The idea is that the user on the iphone create, delete edit data, and then send the db to the computer to check it there, no need to edit in the computer the data (send over internet, so web service and ROR showing the edited db necessary)

I have managed to make work my basic operations on the iphone and basic db in ROR,
but I need to know please the following...

- the coredata saves the data in *.sqlite format, but my ROR db uses a *.sqlite3 format,
  so do I configure the ROR to use adapter: sqlite??? (what else to do plz??)

or do I need some other step to change the sqlite to sqlite3 format,

I just need some basic caching, so its possible to just sent the sqlite file and open it (processed or not)in my ROR??

or is there something else involved??

ok thank you for helping the noob ;)
cheers, good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much simpler to save the file straight to disk than to chuck it into the database, although both are options. To store the file in the db you need to put it in a field for :binary data (blob in mysql). There is a little more to it than that, but it follows a similar pattern to what is required for storing images in a db and that is a popular topic so you should be able to find that info fairly easily. To put it on a disk you just write out the file. I am interested in how you are uploading this file to the server in the first place. Not that it is complex, just that there is more than one way to go about that. Finally I would suggest that you consider using a full blown db like postgres* or mysql to do something like store binary data.

You may be interested in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735147/rails-storing-binary-files-in-database) that discusses this topic.

And [this tutorial](http://mattberther.com/2007/10/19/uploading-files-to-a-database-using-rails) briefly covers storing a files in a db using rails.

*my fave

Comment: To clarify, you should never try to "open" an uploaded database, sqlight or otherwise in your rails app. A rails application normally uses a  database for application data. If you want to read the file directly from rails you can get a ruby gem to read just about any type of database you could imagine. If you just need to back up the file then just do that. Save it someplace, like the database or on the filesystem. Don't worry about 'opening ' it with ror.

Comment: oh, much clearer for me tnx,  (I need to open the db in the computer that downloads it..) so now the question is, if I open the uploaded database would ROR  import the opened db file in the necessary fields?? ie, name, address date, etc? thank you!

Comment: Ok then. What you should be doing then is store the file someplace on disk so that you can access it directly and in your ruby code in one of your controllers (or the models if you set it up that way) you would write the code to access your sqlite db file. You should use the ruby-sqlite gem to read the file. The gem install instructions and documentation can be found at http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org

Comment: As to weather you put most of the code in the controller or the model it makes little difference. I would assume that you will have a model that will hold data (like the filename, owner,  and any other meta-data) for uploaded *.sqlite files, so you could easily put a portion of the code to read the file in there. It would not be very hard to store the file in the db as an alternative but there doesn't seem to be any good reason to do that.