# How can I view a pdf file that is encoded (as base64) in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, iframe, heroku

I currently have a site on heroku and am using postgreSQL. When I upload pdf files to the database, I encode them to base64 and save them as text. I can click a link decode the file and download it without a problem; however, I'm having trouble having a page where I have an iframe with the pdf file within it. How can I feed the freshly decoded file to iframe? Even without iframe, how can I just decode the file and have it as a page?

I'm thinking that I could create a pdf controller, decode the file and have show open the file, but I can't even get that to work.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Here's what I have so far.

```
def create
  @course = Course.find(params[:note][:id])
  params[:note][:content].tempfile = Base64.encode64(open(params[:note][:content].tempfile).to_a.join)
  params[:note][:filename] = params[:note][:content].original_filename
  params[:note][:contenttype] = params[:note][:content].content_type
  @note = @course.notes.build(:content => params[:note][:content].tempfile, :filename => params[:note][:filename],        
  :contenttype => params[:note][:contenttype])
  if @note.save
      flash[:success] = "File Uploaded!"
      redirect_to root_path
end
```

This saves the file as base64 without a problem. I'm not too sure about the next part though.

```
def show
  @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  @notecon = @note.content
  decoded_data=Base64.decode64(@notecon)
  file_name = "test"
  @temp_file = Tempfile.new("filename-#{Time.now}")
  File.open(@temp_file, 'wb') {|f| f.write(decoded_data)}
end
```

Now, in the view, I have no clue what to put as the filepath.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://localhost:3000/app/views/notes/test&embedded=true" 
style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I can't even figure out how to post a pdf file that's saved on my drive.
Thanks again!

Comment: Show us what you did thus far, it's hard to help you when there is no starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the

```
send_data
```

method  in action controller to send the file to the browser. You will need to set the content type, how it should be displayed by the browser etc.

```
send_data(@pdf, :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => "myfile.pdf", :disposition => "inline"
```

:deposition=>'inline'  instruct the browser to display it inside the browser.

You can find similar examples here where they upload an image to the database

http://over9000.org/rails/saving-ruby-on-rails-attachments-as-blobs

https://gist.github.com/macek/610596

[Rails: Storing binary files in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735147/rails-storing-binary-files-in-database)

Consider storing the pdf to an Amazon S3 bucket or other cloud storage . PaperClip gem can do it trasparently for you. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip‎ . Paperclip can save to database too.

If you still plan to go with database storage, be aware of its de-merits
[Rails: Storing binary files in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735147/rails-storing-binary-files-in-database)